# How do I put text on top in flash?

Tags: flash

I am using

```
this.attackMovie
```

function for loading some objects, but they are above the score text i have because they spawn at random position. How can i put my text on top so every loaded object at random position is below my text?

Comment: Are you using AS2 or AS3? You should also copy-paste the whole code snippet that is giving you grief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use attachMovie, you can define a z-index to attach it at. If you don't, then flash will put it right at the top of the display stack, above everything else.

What you should do here is to make sure the z-index you use for 'some objects that are placed at random position' to be less than the z-index of 'score text'

You should also look at the swapDepths function.

Basically, you need to make sure the 'score text' always has the highest z-index (depth)

Comment: i did it, i was using this.getNextHighestDepth and i replaced it with 10+i because i use a loop for this, thanks for the answer